# How to use props with ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a passed prop in a ternary operator, but I can't seem to get it working. I have included a sample of the code, not the actual code, but I feel this captures the issue without necessarily including a long line of code. I want to add a condition: if props passed ="Good" then let the statement change to "that's a nice word"

```
       function Speak(props){

        return(

        <div>
        {props.word}==="Good" ? "that's a nice word" : 
"Its not nice to say"{props.word}
        </div>
        );





    function Speak(props){

    return(

    <div>
  // I want to add a condition
    It is not nice to say <strong>{props.word}</strong>!
    </div>
    );
```

I want to add a condition: if props passed ="good" then let the statement change to "that's a nice word"

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep your conditional logic in brackets `{ ... }`.

```
function Speak(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.word === "Good"
                ? <span>That's a nice word!</span>
                : <span>It is not nice to say <strong>{props.word}</strong>!</span>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Great tip! that's the solution

Comment: @8SINS Happy to help! Please accept this answer as the solution if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi @8SINS. On Stack Overflow we say thank you by [accepting answers which helped us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). There's a green checkmark next to the answer on the left which you tick :) This also helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can say something like this:

```
const Speak = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {props.word === "Good" ? 
        <span>That's a nice word.</span> : 
        <span>It's not nice to say <b>{ props.word }</b>.</span>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what about the other {props.word}  should I add it like this ...'It's not nice to say' props.word... I actually tried that and it gave me a syntax error

Comment: @ Raul <b>Its not nice to say</b> is dependant on {props.word } to complete the statement

Comment: Sorry, i forgot `const` Speak = (props) => {}